# Confusion the use of resolve() and then() methods with Promise

Tags: javascript

I was learning promises in JS and the use of `resolve()` and `then()` is a bit confusing me. So, as far as I understood, the `promises` serve as a wrapper for asynchronous operations and the reason to use `promise` is to ensure the easier chaining. Right? Then, the reason to use `resolve()` is that it points to the place where we get data and after that we do something with that data thanks to `then()`. Is that correct? if not can you explain why to use `resolve()` and `then()` in simple words.

Comment: resolve (or reject) resolves a Promise, i.e. changes its state from Pending to Resolved/Rejected, at this point any "queued" `.then` callbacks are called, .then is how a Promises resolved value is used

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you for your kind comments. So, resolve() means the place where we get some data from asynchronous operation. RIght? For example, resolve(request.responseText)

Comment: @JaromandaX, please I really need your help, I am just trying to get resolve() so it is easier to understand.

Comment: You would call `resolve` once you have the `data` from an asynchronous operation which then causes the function you pass to `then` to be called with the `data` you passed to `resolve`. So yes I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: @RockySims, hey dude thank you for your comments, please can you create an answer to the question so I could accept it certainly if you do not mind:)

Comment: You should show some code, and point to which part is hard to understand. What you pass to resolve becomes the argument to the callback passed to `then`.

Comment: @Pop created an answer. There are a lot of other good answers now. I'd recommend you accept whichever one helped you the most.

Comment: @RockySims, yeah there are good answers including yours but you were the first who helped:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise is a placeholder for data that will be available later.

```js
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log('waiting for async...');
  //wait for some asynchronous thing to provide data
  setTimeout(function() {resolve('theData');}, 2000);
});

promise.then(function(data) {
  console.log('promise was resolved with data: ' + data);
});

console.log('listening for promise resolution');
```

The above snippet will log:

"waiting for async..."

and immediately after

"listening for promise resolution"

then wait for async to finish then

"promise was resolved with data: theData"

Answer (score 2):

`resolve` and `reject` are just ways to tell the caller that your promise is completed (it's been `resolved` or `rejected`). `.then` can be used, but I prefer to use `await` when I can.

Using `return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {});` is a good way to wrap things to make then asynchrous which is awesome, but most of the time, if something returns a `promise` (like a lot of libraries are starting to do), then you can just `await` it. Same thing as calling `.then` on a promise (from a 10,000 foot level)

Example:

```js
const myPromise = async () => {
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout( () => {
     resolve('im done!');
    }, 1000);
  })
}

// Use .then to call your promise in a 'callback way'
myPromise().then( text => console.log(text));

async function awaitThePromise() {
// using await to call your promise
 const result = await myPromise();
  console.log(result);
}

awaitThePromise();
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Promise, resolve, and reject

`new Promise()`, `Promise.resolve()`, and `Promise.reject()` all creates a promise instance.

#### Then and catch

`.then()` and `.catch()` are used to react to the asynchronous value returned by the promise instance.

#### What are the difference then?

**`new Promise()`** is to *execute asynchronous operations*. It must resolve or reject with a value.

**`Promise.resolve()`** and **`Promise.reject()`** is to *wrap a value* into a resolved or rejected promise value.

**`.then()`** is to react with a resolved promise with its value.

**`.catch()`** is to react with a rejected promise with its value.

#### Conclusion

All promises must be initiated with one of `new Promise()`, `Promise.resolve()`, or `Promise.reject()`. Only then you are able to use `.then()` or `.catch()`.

Just think of it like normal English, you only use the word "then" after something is done (making a promise, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If it helps you, I see promises as future values. I like to use the analogy of a ticket. For example when you buy food you get a ticket. You already pay for the food (you initiated the action to get your food), but the food is not ready yet so, you get a place holder (ticket), something that you can exchange later for the food. Now, `resolve` is how internally they notify that the food is ready. And `then` is where you subscribe to be notified.

So, they `resolve(food)` and you get notified `then(food)`. By you get notified I mean your callback is called with the food.

Answer (score 1):

The `then` method is used for running code after the previous promise resolves.

The `resolve` method is used to do two things: 1) end a Promise; and 2) if data is passed into it, it passes that data into a `then` callback.

This makes it easy to write code that runs after other code. For example:

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)arr.push_back(i);
  resolve(arr);
});
p.then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

The callback in `p.then` will run only after the previous Promise resolves, i.e. calls `resolve()`.
You don't have to pass data into `resolve` if you don't want to - just do `resolve(null)` or the like.